# Magento Creation of coupon

Tags: magento, coupon

I tried to create the coupons but not able to understand How to add coupons in magento? and how many types of coupons can be created in magento

Answer (score 1):

Go to Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules and click on Add New Rule button. In the General Information page in the coupon menu, select the Specific Coupon option. Enter a code in the coupon code field.

You can mention the code manually or opt auto generation option. For more details refer http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-create-coupon-codes-in-magento-beginners-tutorial-1